# What is the idiomatic way to create a new default record in a REST webservice?

Tags: rest

So let's say I have a REST webservice for managing `person` records:

```
{
  "id": <uuid>,
  "name": <String>
}
```

So I understand, in idiomatic REST, to create a new `person` with a given name, I would normally handle this through a POST call:

And this would result in the server assigning an id, and echoing the result:

```
POST /person
request body:
{
  "name": "Jane Doe"
}
response body:
{
  "id": "server-generated-uuid",
  "name": "Jane Doe"
}
```

But what if I want the server to generate a default record?  I.e. for the server to supply the name and id?

How is this normally handled?  Would the endpoint just accept an empty object?

```
POST /person
request body:
response body:
{
  "id": "server-generated-uuid",
  "name": "Jane Doe"
}
```

Or would you normally have a special route, like `POST /person/new`?

Answer (score 0):

> How is this normally handled?

On the web, we'd use a form, right?  It could be a simple "do this" button, or it could be a collection of input controls with the "default" values filled in.

Notice that with [hypertext](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven) forms, the client code doesn't need to know where to submit the form, because that information is included in the form metadata.

Because the origin server that provides the representation of the form gets to decide where the form should be submitted, you've got a bit of extra freedom to choose what the request-target should be.  Reasonable answers include:

- a request target that handles that kind of form submission exclusively (ex: /person/new); with separate handlers for each kind of form, it can be easier to see what has been happening when your operators are reviewing access logs
- a request target that provides access to the index / collection where this new resource will appear; by specifying one of the documents that changes as the request-target, you get to leverage HTTP's built in [cache invalidation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4).

An alternative, if the client already knows which identifier should be assigned to the new resource, is to use PUT with a "default" payload, and then have the server implementation fill in the missing details.

```
PUT /person/40af7aaa-9d5c-4c58-87fb-ecb34f34eeea
Content-Type: application/json

{
}
```

```
201 Created
Content-Type: application/json
Location: /person/40af7aaa-9d5c-4c58-87fb-ecb34f34eeea
Content-Location: /person/40af7aaa-9d5c-4c58-87fb-ecb34f34eeea

{
  "id": "40af7aaa-9d5c-4c58-87fb-ecb34f34eeea",
  "name": "Jane Doe"
}
```

The semantics of HTTP [PUT](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.4) constrain the semantics of the request, but the server has a lot of freedom in how it handles the request (see [Fielding 2002](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-tag/2002Apr/0207.html)).  In particular, the [RFC 7231](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.4) explicitly permits the server to "change" the representation provided in the PUT request-body

> When a PUT representation is inconsistent with the target resource, the origin server SHOULD either make them consistent, by transforming the representation or ....